# CruiseControl.NET Continuous Integration Blocking File Access

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Our Continuous Integration process appears to be executing programs that are in contention for for files.  During the build, certain pdb's aren't able to be copied because they are in use by another process.

**Question: Ideally it would be faster to have the concurrent building of each project executing however I was wondering if this would be the cause of the contention and if so is there a way to mitigate the problem.  Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to have the projects building at the same time you can put them in the same queue (just add `queue="someCommonQueueName"` to the project node in ccnet.config

Comment: I just implemented your answer and it works great!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the /m flag with msbuild I have seen this cause problems if your solution and project dependency structure is not just right.  I found this [post](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2007/11/msbuild-multithreaded-building-in.html) that looked interesting and maybe it will help you.

I looked at my solution structure and I had a WCF service project that was not added properly to the solution.  I removed the service and re-added the service and I was able to build with the /m:2 utilizing 2 procs.  What I found was the error that you see in the build process will point to the source of the problem.